# Are we supposed to be creating player prefab?

Tags: unity, game-design

This may seem like a dumb question, but I want a single player object for the entirety of my game. However when I load multiple levels obviously I need to reload the player so I would create a player prefab and instantiate him. However, it seems counterintuitive as prefabs are for objects you want to create multiple instances of easily, correct?
Also, I need values to be carried over accross levels for my player object therefore I guess I would need a static global singleton to store the player objects.

Hence the dilemna and confusion! Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Games really aren't about "supposed to" - they're about what works and what doesn't.

If creating a player prefab makes it easier for you to spawn the player avatar in any scene you need them in, and that works for your needs, then it's a good solution.

No Unity police will knock on your door and say "I heard you used a prefab for an object that's only spawned once. That'll be a bajillion dollar fine" - the tools exist for you to get your work done, so use them the way that makes sense to you.

> Also, I need values to be carried over accross levels for my player object therefore I guess I would need a static global singleton to store the player objects.

Not necessarily. You could also use `DontDestroyOnLoad` or additive scene loading to persist one instance of an object throughout your game, rather than unloading & respawning it every time you change to a new level.

Comment: Good answer! But still would be nice to hear what is most common or recommended to closer follow to the standards

Comment: "If creating a player prefab makes it easier for you to spawn the player avatar in any scene you need them in, and that works for your needs, then it's a good solution." — That's about as close to a standard as you're going to find: use Prefabs where they help.